# Handling POST values Datatables with Django

Tags: ajax, django, datatables

Use Datatables plugin with Django 1.10. Process the data on the server side via POST.

My problem is in capturing all the variables order[x], order[x][dir] and order[x][column] to be included in the queryset, in the POST comes the information more or less like this:

```
draw:1
columns[0][data]:chb_chcl_id
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:false
columns[0][orderable]:false
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:chcl_num_cheque
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:empr_nombre
columns[2][name]:
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
columns[3][data]:cuen_nombre
columns[3][name]:
columns[3][searchable]:true
columns[3][orderable]:true
columns[3][search][value]:
columns[3][search][regex]:false
order[0][column]:5
order[0][dir]:asc
order[1][column]:6
order[1][dir]:asc
start:0
length:5
search[value]:
search[regex]:false
```

But the user can change the columns for the order of the data, so the order[] variables could be more or less, depending on the user's choice.

How can I go through all the order[] variables, I have int with request.POST.getlist('order'), request.POST.getlist('order[]'), request.POST.getlist('order[][column]')

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the list using `request.POST.getlist('order[]')`

Comment: print `request.POST` and check the output